# Shell script to match a string and print the next string on aix machine

Tags: shell, unix, aix

I have a following line as input.

```
Parsing events:hostname='tom';Ipaddress='10.10.10.1';situation_name='sgd_abc_app_a';type='General';
```

Like this there are many fields in a line separated by a delimiter as semi-colon. (But starting with Parsing Events:)

I want to extract only`sgd_abc_app_a` when it matches situation_name.

Thanks
Kulli

Comment: Is `Parsing Events:` placed on a separate line?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest No. Its in the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
sed -n 's/^.*situation_name=//p' input_file| awk -F "'" '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
s="Parsing events: hostname='tom';Ipaddress='10.10.10.1';situation_name='sgd_abc_app_a';type='General';"
awk -F'[=;]' '{ gsub("\047","",$6); print $6 }' <<< $s
```

---

Or with ***sed***:

```
sed -n "s/^Parsing events:.*situation_name='\([^']*\).*/\1/p" <<< $s
```

The output:

```
sgd_abc_app_a
```

Comment: But the situation_name is in different position for some of the lines in the file. Still this code works?

Comment: you should add more context lines to show *situation_name is in different position for some of the lines in the file*

Comment: Can't really predict the position because it has thousands of lines. But it starts with Parsing Events: and ends with END; and situation_name may occur anywhere in between these 2.

Comment: @Kulli, use my sed approach

Answer (score 0):

For your request, it would work no matter the position of `situation_name`

```
$ awk '/situation_name/{match($0,/situation_name=[^;]+/); print substr($0,RSTART+16,RLENGTH-17)}' file
sgd_abc_app_a
```